# Select a range in UISlider

Tags: ios, cocoa, range, uislider

i asked me whether it is possible if i can create a uislider who has 2 handles to select a range. Just like here:

[image]

The problem i am facing is that i dont want to use a custom UIControl Subclass. I need a UISlider subclass or a other solution for this problem, because a lot of the code is based on UISlider specific propertys etc. So is there any possibility to achieve this ?

Comment: You could maybe do it by having two sliders, one on top of the other, and then adjust their values and frames dynamically as the other one changes.  It'd be pretty tricky though.

Comment: hm how did he made it ? http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/091/Purple/v4/6e/e9/95/6ee99507-9eae-b469-44e0-4acc9707752e/mza_386598055151052039.320x480-75.jpg Maybe i could just use 2 imageviews which only can move horizontically and then based on the x position i could set the range... how can i move imageviews only horizontically ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass `UISlider`, but it will be very difficult. Your class should offer quite some new properties, and the old ones won't make much sense at all.

Not sure how your code can be based much on `UISlider` specific things - as everything would change the meaning (i.e. ranges instead of one value).

If you really need a common base class, you could encapsulate ("has-a" relationship) the control in a custom class and let this handle the different types.

I implemented a similar control using a custom view, and it happened to be quite straight forward.

Comment: Ok but my problem is that i have a music player. And i want to keep the ability to move the slider to forward or rewind. So i thought i add two arrows additionally under the slider which i can move along the slider. So i have the 2 arrows which show the range and i have the normal control button on the slider which allows me to forward or rewind the audio file... so how could i achieve that ?

Comment: Either subclass UISlider, or, probably better, build a custom view that has a slider has a subview and manages the two arrows itself.

Comment: and how to manage the arrows by the custom view ? oh man this is getting very complicated

Comment: Building *good* custom controls is always hard work. Here I'd go with two bitmaps, and handling touches in the custom view.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the following example:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/rangeslider

Answer (score 0):

UISlider doesn't provide the functionality you're after, and subclassing UISlider probably won't work out. What would the `value` of such a control be? The value of a slider is a number, but you want it to be a range. Consider a custom control that duplicates the UISlider properties you need.